# Парсинг. На запрос от сайта отдает ответ, а через cURL нет

Tags: php, curl

Сильно увлекаюсь темой парсингом динамических сайтов. Наткнулся на интересный ресурс. Решил его пропарсить. В Chrome на вкладке **Network** посмотрел куда идет запрос, там оказывается он идет через GET. Я скопировал ссылку запроса - перешел на нее - в итоге ответ 403 - мне данные не выдает.

Тогда я скопировал этот запрос: `Copy -> Copy as cURL (bash)` с куками и тд (все как в браузере)
И импортировал этот запрос в Postman, попытался выполнить - но в ответ получаю все ту же 403.

Стало еще интереснее. Хотелось бы разгадать этот ребус. Возможно там создается какая-то метка... или еще что-то.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь!
Очень бы хотелось получить больше опыта в парсинге подобных ресурсов.

Ссылка на динамическую страницу которую пытаюсь парсить: [ссылка](https://fedresurs.ru/search/encumbrances?searchString=9705101614%20&group=Leasing&publishPeriod=%7B%22beginJsDate%22:%222019-08-14T00:00:00.000Z%22,%22endJsDate%22:%222019-08-14T00:00:00.000Z%22%7D)

Ссылка куда идет запрос с Network: [ссылка](https://fedresurs.ru/backend/encumbrances?startIndex=0&pageSize=15&additionalSearchFnp=true&searchString=9705101614%20&group=Leasing&publishDateStart=2019-08-14&publishDateEnd=2019-08-14)

Comment: значит не все как в браузере

Comment: @teran но я же полностью скопировал запрос, с куками, с хеадерами и тд...

Comment: Значит смотрят кто обращается к запросу. как минимум может проверяться `referer` который есть когда идет поиск и которого нет когда вы делаете запрос по ссылке из Network.

Comment: `referef` тоже есть. Но все равно я получаю 403 :(

Comment: @NikolajSarry проверил - реферер передается. я полностью копирую из Network запрос, там он копируется со всеми заголовками и куками и тд.

Comment: Сайт не открывается вообще, ошибка протокола. "HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR"

Comment: @sanmai, у меня открывается.

Comment: проверил. если добавить Referer: то возвращает 200 и json

Comment: @DmitryKozlov вы можете это оформить curl кодом для php и отправить ответом на вопрос. Если это действительно так - я выберу ответ как решение.

Comment: просто открыл страницу. нажал на кнопку поиск. в network скопировал реферер. перешел по второй ссылке. получил 403. зашел в заголовки. нажал "изменить и отправить" вставил реферер от страницы. в ответ получил 200 и json. Ну а ответ не сильно полезен для SO

Comment: @DmitryKozlov а пробовали ли это сделать через curl? Сработает ли такой подход?

Comment: На сколько я вижу, у них на сервере используется HTTP 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я провел експеримент и определил минимальный набор данных чтоб запрос проходил:

1. Cookie
2. Referer
3. User-agent

Вот этот код работает у меня.

```
<?php
$url = "https://fedresurs.ru/backend/encumbrances?startIndex=0&pageSize=15&additionalSearchFnp=true&searchString=9705101614%20&group=Leasing&publishDateStart=2019-08-14&publishDateEnd=2019-08-14";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://fedresurs.ru/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Cookie: fedresurscookie=0c715349c5d062692fcca6a3630ab3b0"]);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($response);
```

Так же, возможно, придется включить HTTP 2.0 директивой `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0)`